# Get the value of a column of table filtered with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, function

I have a jQuery dynamic table being made up perfectly. here is the table below:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="order_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>                               
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                              
        <tr id="row1">
            <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="12 "> 
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">Nokia110</td>
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">1</td> 
            <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="1" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="13 ">
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">Samsung</td>
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">1</td>
            <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="2" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row3">
            <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="11 "> <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">$name</td>
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">1</td>
            <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="3" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row4">
            <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="12 "> 
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">Nokia110</td>
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">2</td>
            <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="4" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row5">
            <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="12 "> 
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">Nokia110</td>
            <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">3</td>
            <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="5" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I have used `<input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="">` for sending the product id to server purpose.

What my problem is I need to have the sum value of quantity of a particular product. for example for pid=13.

I have used this jQuery for searching the table but not finding the value based on pid=13. Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {  
    search_table($(this).val());  
});  

function search_table(value) {   
    $('#order_table tr').each(function() {  
        var found = 'false';  
        $(this).each(function() {  
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)  
            {  
                found = 'true';  
            }  
        });  

        if(found == 'true')  
        {  
            $(this).show();  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            $(this).hide();  
        }  
    });  
}
```

I am sorry if I made a mistake as I am newbie in jQuery. Please help me to find the total quantity based on a particular product id.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to search for table cell `td` inside each `tr`, then look for the value instead of text, as `pid=13` is saved as:

```
<input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="13 ">
```

Also, update your HTML markup, as right now the above input is not inside any `td` which is not valid. Put it inside any `td` for this to work.

**Code:**

```
function search_table(value) {
  $('#order_table tr').each(function() {
    var found = 'false';
    $('td', this).each(function() {    
      var pid = $('.pid', this).val() || '';
      if (pid.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        found = 'true';
        return false;
      }
    });
    $(this).toggle(found == 'true');
  });
}
```

```js
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  search_table($(this).val());
});

function search_table(value) {
  $('#order_table tr').each(function() {
    var found = 'false';
    $('td', this).each(function() {
      var pid = $('.pid', this).val() || '';
      if (pid.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        found = 'true';
        return false;
      }
    });
    $(this).toggle(found == 'true');
  });

  var quantity = 0;
  $(".selected_item_quantity:visible").each(function() {
    quantity += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  
  console.log(quantity)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..." /><br/>
<br/>
<table class="table table-hover" id="order_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row1">
      <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">
        <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="12 "> Nokia110
      </td>
      <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">1</td>
      <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="1" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
      <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">
        <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="13 ">Samsung</td>
      <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">1</td>
      <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="2" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
      <td id="ok" class="selected_item_name">
        <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="11 ">$name</td>
      <td id="ok" class="selected_item_quantity">1</td>
      <td id="ok"><button name="delete" id="3" class="btn_remove"><i class="feather icon-trash-2 f-30 text-c-blue"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. I can access the rows based on pid. and I can get the total rows based on class with this  var quantity= 0;
  
  $(".selected_item_quantity").each(function () {
   quantity+= parseInt($(this).text());
  });     but this code returns sum of all the rows. How can I get the sum of only rows selected based on pid class? thanks again.

Comment: You can do it using var quantity = 0;
  $(".selected_item_quantity:visible").each(function() {
    quantity += parseInt($(this).text());
  }); I have updated demo as well. You can see sum updated as you search.